# ConcurrentDictionary in WCF chat service, can add but not remove

Tags: c#, wcf, concurrentdictionary

So I have created a chat service using WCF and so far everything works as it should. The only issue I have is when the user logouts out. I am using a `ConcurrentDictionary` to hold all the connected clients and when use `TryRemove` it always returns false. Here is the code.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public class ComsService : IMessageComs
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<Client, IMessageComsCallBack> clients = new ConcurrentDictionary<Client, IMessageComsCallBack>();

    public IMessageComsCallBack CurrentCallback
    {
        get
        {
            return OperationContext.Current.
                   GetCallbackChannel<IMessageComsCallBack>();
        }
    }

    public Client ClientConnect(string userName)
    {
        var exists = clients.Where(x => x.Key.UserName == userName);

        if (exists.Count() == 0)
        {
            Client c = new Client();
            c.UserName = userName;

            if (this.clients.TryAdd(c, CurrentCallback))
            {
                // Let everyone know that a new user has connected
                foreach (KeyValuePair<Client, IMessageComsCallBack> kvp in clients)
                {
                    if(!kvp.Key.Equals(c))
                        kvp.Value.RefreshClients(clients.Keys.ToList());
                }

                return c;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
        else
            return exists.First().Key;
    }

    public bool RemoveUser(Client user)
    {
        IMessageComsCallBack _callback;

        if (clients.ContainsKey(user)) // this is pointless, I know but was just a test
        {

            if (clients.TryRemove(user, out _callback))
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (IMessageComsCallBack callback in clients.Values)
                    {
                        callback.UserLeft(user);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

I know it wasn't required but I also added a check to see if the client was already in the list before removing it. This resulted in false also.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:
Just had a thought and modified my logout method like so and it seems to work. I can only assume that something has happened to the `client` value and its no longer the same as the one in the list.

```
public bool RemoveUser(Client user)
{
        IMessageComsCallBack _callback;

        var exists = clients.Where(x => x.Key.UserName == user.UserName);

        if(exists.Count() > 0)
        {
            if (clients.TryRemove(exists.First().Key, out _callback))
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (IMessageComsCallBack callback in clients.Values)
                    {
                        callback.UserLeft(user);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that `client.ContainsKey(user)` returns `false`? If that's the case it's not surprising that `TryRemove` also fails. Where does the `user` argument value come from?

Comment: `TryRemove` always return false. I added `client.Contains(user)` just as a test to see if there was an issue with the `TryRemove`. The `user` value comes from the connected client which actually gets the value from the`login` method in the above code. i.e. the `client` is created in the `login` method and is returned back to the client app. When the client app logs out it passes the client value back.

Answer (score 2):

You use your client object as the key of your dictionary. When the client sends his logout message, he sends you a `Client`  object which has just been deserialized by WCF. If you have not overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, the `ConcurrentDictionary` will not realize your original client represents the same client as the one passed into `RemoveClient`.

Consider overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

One case I can think of that would prevent this from working is if someone kills the client process or if the connection drops. The client would not send a call to `RemoveClient` in that case, and the object would linger in your dictionary. 
If you use a Duplex WCF service, you can subscribe to an event when the client disconnects, allowing you to always remove the client if he is not connected.

Comment: I will give the override a go now